# Can't Resolve Error: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements for Debug in xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, build, code-signing

I am trying to build for debugging. I am getting the error: The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

This worked every day until last night. The last time it worked was when I clicked on Always Allow on the codesign question that pops up when you build where it says it wants to sign using key "my key name" in your keychain.

I have an entitlements plist already that I used for creating my ad hoc distribution. I have updated build settings for Code Signing Entitlements for Debug to include this Entitlements.plist file.

I have verified that my profiles are up to date. My Team Provisioning Profile had expired, so I renewed it. I even tried creating new profiles. Still didn't help

I have tried both my developer profile and my distribution profile in the build settings under Code Signing Identity for Debug.

I am completely stuck. Can anyone give me new advice?

Comment: I found an answer. Since I can't answer my own question for 8 hours, my answer is broken into 2 comments:

Comment: I finally got this to work. 

1) In the left column of xcode, I clicked on my project name.
2) I clicked on Build Settings
3) There are 4 columns: Resolved, myProjectName (with an orange icon), myProjectName (with an xcode icon), and IOS Default.

Comment: 4) In the column with the orange icon and the row for Code Signing Entitlements (Debug row), I removed the Entitlements.plist file name from that column, but left it in the column with the xcode icon.
5) In the row for Code Signing Identity (Debug), I chose iPhone Developer in both the column with the orange icon and the xcode icon. I used the Automatic Profile selector.

This fixed my problem. Please not the other things I did in my question as these may also have had an impact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally got this to work.

1) In the left column of xcode, I clicked on my project name.

2) I clicked on Build Settings

3) There are 4 columns: Resolved, myProjectName (with an orange icon), myProjectName (with an xcode icon), and IOS Default.

4) In the column with the orange icon and the row for Code Signing Entitlements (Debug row), I removed the Entitlements.plist file name from that column, but left it in the column with the xcode icon.

5) In the row for Code Signing Identity (Debug), I chose iPhone Developer in both the column with the orange icon and the xcode icon. I used the Automatic Profile selector.

This fixed my problem. Please not the other things I did in my question as these may also have had an impact.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, but I find this solution absolutely befuddling.  You state in step 3 about seeing 4 columns.  In order to see this, you have 2 options under Build Settings:  Basic/All (select All), and Combined/Levels (select Levels).  The default was Combined.  Now I click Combined, I do see 4 columns.  However, I don't see an orange icon.  At my bundle level, I select my developer profile, but it won't run on the device.

Comment: I should add, in my Entitlements file, I changed the value for "Can be debugged" to YES.  With NO, it will run on the device, but I can't debug.

Comment: Similar circumstances, I had to renew my dev certificate, and now I can't debug on a device because the entitlements are invalid.

Comment: ok, in xcode 4.3.2, there is no longer an orange icon, but the message is the same. In the second column (the one to the right of the column marked Resolved), I removed the Entitlements.plist filename from that column. Currently, in the row for Code Signing Identity (Debug), I only have iPhone Developer in the 3rd column with the xcode icon.

Answer (score 0):

This message can come up when there's a problem with the provisioning profile. I got this message when I tried running on a device that did not have the latest provisioning profile. I simply reloaded the provisioning profile from the Developer portal, then made sure the Debug/Release signing used the latest version. Then it ran fine.